# How to implement login and registration (forms) on the (first) Index page in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to create a webapplication, in which a user will be prompted to log in as soon as he or she visits the webapplication (the thing that I am trying to achieve looks much like the Tumblr homepage on first time visit).

All looks well, but whenever I submit one form, the other form will also submit. Since I have to use both `project_name.Models.LoginModel` and `project_name.Models.RegisterModel`, things get complicated for me here aswell. How can I make use of these two different models in one (`index.cshtml`) view and how do I prevent the two (seperate) forms from being submit both at the same time when I only click a submit button belonging to one certain form?

What should I change in my following code?:

My `Index.cshtml`:

```
@model Rent_a_Car.Models.LoginModel @* <- My guess is that this is not a correct way to approach this problem? *@

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<div class="registrate">
    <h2>Rent-a-Car</h2>
    <h4>Register</h4>
    <hr />
    @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary()

        <p>-</p>@*
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "form-control text-box single-line", @name = "E-mail", @placeholder = "E-mail" })
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control text-box single-line", @name = "Wachtwoord", @placeholder = "Wachtwoord" })
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "form-control text-box single-line", @name = "Bevestig", @placeholder = "Bevestig uw wachtwoord" })
        </div>*@
    }
</div>

<div class="welcome">
    <h4>Log in</h4>
    <hr />
    @using (Html.BeginForm(new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl })) {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <p></p>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "form-control text-box single-line", @name = "E-mail", @placeholder = "E-mail" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control text-box single-line", @name = "Wachtwoord", @placeholder = "Wachtwoord" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe)
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe)
        </div>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Inloggen" />
    }
    <hr />
</div>
```

My `HomeController.cs`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Transactions;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Security;
using DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet;
using Microsoft.Web.WebPages.OAuth;
using WebMatrix.WebData;
using Rent_a_Car.Filters;
using Rent_a_Car.Models;

namespace Rent_a_Car.Controllers
{
[InitializeSimpleMembership]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(string returnUrl)
    {
        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;

        return View();
    }

    // POST: /

    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Index(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid && WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, persistCookie: model.RememberMe))
        {
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        }

        ModelState.AddModelError("", "De ingevulde gebruikersnaam of wachtwoord is onjuist ingevoerd.");
        return View(model);
    }

    private ActionResult RedirectToLocal(string returnUrl)
    {
        if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
        {
            return Redirect(returnUrl);
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
    }
```

And `AccountModels.cs` is left default (can this be changed aswell to add for example address data to an account?)

(There's only one button, but I would like to add one sooner to the registration form aswell, but currently one button already sends more than one form, which I want to prevent from happening and just send the one form the button is supposed to post.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you know, you can only use one model as the model for a view. Therefore, the only path forward is to create a class that encompasses these two other classes:

```
public class LoginRegisterViewModel
{
    public LoginModel Login { get; set; }
    public RegisterModel Register { get; set; }
}
```

Then, in your view, you would use `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Login.Username, ...)` instead of `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Username, ...)`, for example.

As far as both being posted at the same time, that's not what's really happening. The fields are segregated into separate HTML forms, so only one set of the other will be posted, not both. However, your post action only accepts `LoginModel`, so only the properties that exist on that will be bound, regardless of which form you post.

Instead, your post action should accept the new `LoginRegisterViewModel`. Only the set of fields that exist in the form that you submit will be posted, and they will all be prefixed with either `Login` or `Register`, corresponding to the two properties on `LoginRegisterViewModel`. Only one or the other will be instantiated by the modelbinder, as a result. The other will be null. Therefore you can test in your post action which is non-null and branch accordingly to either login or register the user.

Comment: I did add a `LoginRegisterViewModel` with the two models `LoginModel` and `RegisterModel` and added `@model Rent_a_Car.Models.LoginRegisterViewModel` at the top of my `Index.cshtml` file. I also changed all of the textbox codes to apply to the new model included to the index view. All seems fine but when I cick on the  log in button and/or registration button, the following exception is thrown: `The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'Rent_a_Car.Models.LoginModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'Rent_a_Car.Models.LoginRegisterViewModel'.` Is controller wrong?